# Empty File after writing

Tags: python, file

Keep trying to write to file but the file is empty :-( I've tried so many things, feel like I'm spinning. I'm a newbie as you can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import shutil
import re
import csv
import sys      # imports the sys module
infile = csv.reader(open("March9small.csv", "rU"), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
reader=csv.reader(infile)
new_rows_list=[]
for row in infile:
    new_rows_list.append(row)
    print new_rows_list

outfile = csv.writer(open("March9small-revised.csv","wt"), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
for i in new_rows_list:
    outfile.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you pass `csv.reader` to `csv.reader`?

Here's the simplified version without an intermediate list with nested `with` context managers:

```
import csv

with open("March9small.csv", "rU") as infile:
    with open("March9small-revised.csv","wt") as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Make sure you understand what is going on here - if not, feel free to ask in comments.